# mongodb How to find restaurants with grades above 12

Tags: mongodb

[image: mongodb How to find restaurants with grades above 12]

mongodb How to find restaurants with grades above 12

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get just restaurant with a score of more than 12
you should use `aggregate` like this

```
db.collection('test').aggregate([
  {
    '$project': {
      'address':1,
      'district':1,
      'province':1,
      'resturant': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$resturant', 
          'as': 't', 
          'cond': {
            '$gt': [
              '$$t.score', 12
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and if you want to get all doc with a restaurant score of more than 12
use `$elemMatch` like this

```
db.collection('test).find({resturant:{$elemMatch:{score:{$gt:12}}})
```